# Objects not supported by structuredClone

Tags: javascript

I've been using `structuredClone` for deep cloning, instead of the cumbersome `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo))`. However, in the list of supported types, [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm#supported_types):

> - Object: but only plain objects (e.g. from object literals).

I'm not sure what would be a *non-plain* object, an object instantiated by a class? It makes little sense, because `structuredClone` seems to work on those as well.

In short: what kind of objects are not supported by `structuredClone`?

Comment: I know that MDN is not ECMA, and I've seen errors in MDN before... so, would that be a wrong information?

Comment: Try this: `class Foo { getValue() { return 42; }}; structuredClone(new Foo()).getValue()`. Plain objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, but there are lots of objects who don't. This prototype information is lost.

Comment: "*an object instantiated by a class?*" - yes, precisely those. "*`structuredClone` seems to work on those as well.*" - it doesn't. Which ones did you try?

Comment: @Bergi I tested only looking properties (primitives, nested objects, arrays etc) created by the class, not methods (as Felix said) or other class info (as Lionel said).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure what would be a *non-plain* object, an object instantiated by a class?

Correct. Objects instantiated by a class *can* be cloned, but they'll be plain objects in the cloned version, so information may be lost.

```js
class X {
    prop = 1
    static staticProp = 2
    method() { return 3 }
}

const x = new X()
const clone = structuredClone(x)

console.log(clone) // { prop: 1 }
console.log(clone instanceof X) // false
console.log(clone.constructor.name) // Object
console.log(clone.constructor.staticProp) // undefined
console.log(clone.method()) // Uncaught TypeError: clone.method is not a function
```